# Discord.js Ping @Here role

Tags: javascript, discord.js

How do you get the @here role?

Things I tried:

- sending `@here` (doesn't ping)
- interaction.guild.roles.fetch("@here") (not a real role)
- '<@&'+threadId+'>' (comes up @deleted-role)

I don't see it in the documentation anywhere but it's really hard to search since search engines ignore the @

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@here` is not a role. It simply mentions `@everyone` but only pings everyone online. You would need to use the everyone role.

```js
const role = interaction.guild.roles.everyone
```

Note, the everyone role ID is the same as the guild ID, so for things like overwrite editing, you should use the guild ID

```js
await channel.permissionOverwrites.edit(interaction.guild.id, {
  SEND_MESSAGES: false
})
```

Comment: I don't want to ping everyone, i want to ping just the people who have joined a thread

Comment: @stackers you should have included that in the question before, but it's not like threads have a certain given role. What I understood was you wanted to get the `@here` role object

Comment: Also, I just tested, and sending `@everyone` in a thread only mentions the people in the thread

Comment: okay, that might work, I will have to test it

Comment: i think it will work, but i still cant figure out how to get my bot to ping the role, it highlights the role but does not ping anyone

Comment: @stackers seems that I made a mistake while testing, the alt didn't have permissions to use threads. Pinging everyone does ping people outside of the thread. There is no way to do it on people only inside of the thread